# RSpec Factory Girl methods not loaded when running specific .spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot, rspec3

I've few `create(:user, :registering)` in my test suite. When I run

```
$ bundle exec rspec
```

Everything works fine. But When run a specific .spec:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_profile_spec.rb
```

I got a error telling method `create` is not defined. I've the correct configuration for this sintax work:

```
# spec/support/factory_girl.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

and

```
# rails_helper.rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

Which configuration is missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you requiring rails_helper in each of your spec files?

Comment: No, I'm not. I should?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Add this as the correct answer!